# Switch from RPi 2 to RPi B+

Tags: pi-2, pi-b+

I was doing a project on a Raspberry Pi 2. Recently, something happened and now the board is not working. I'm planning to replace it with a RPi Model B+. Can I use the same SD card to boot without formatting it? Do I have to install a fresh OS on the SD card and install all other software, or can I simply insert the previous one and it'll work?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming you are referring to **Raspbian**, the same SD card should work unless you have removed `kernel.img` from the boot partition and/or corresponding directories from `/lib/modules`.

If you are referring to an OS that is Pi 2/3 only (e.g., various forms of Ubuntu) then no, it will not work on a B+.

Also, if you have specified a specific kernel in `/boot/config.txt`, then comment that line out.  You can also check to see if one ended up there some other way.

```
#kernel=whatever
```

That's "commented out" (`#`).  This way the bootloader will be able to select the correct kernel.

Comment: I assumed this was the case, but wasn't sure what kind of shenanigans might be going on with the firmware controller.

Comment: @Jacobm001 There's only one `bootcode.bin`, so all models use that.  I'm pretty sure it does make some distinctions, though (e.g., it is what decides which kernel to load if one isn't specified in `config.txt`, which I should edit something in about that...).  But in any case, if the OP was using `raspi-update` (or the OS does the equivalent), it will still apply to all of them.

Comment: @goldilocks The Pi was running Raspbian on it. I have not removed any files from the SD card. I have already changed the GPU memory to 256MB and arm_freq to 1000Hz. So the changes happened in config.txt will make any problems if I use the SD card in RPI B+?

Comment: Well, no one promises all B+s will be okay at 1 Ghz but I believe most of them turn out to be.  You can also set `force_turbo=0` and `arm_freq_min=600` so that the kernel can vary the frequency with load.  256MB for the GPU seems excessive but that is up to you -- I think only fairly specialized purposes involving video processing would require that, and it will only *hurt* the performance of the GUI, which will never need more than 64 MB (if that), sans video playback.   CPU RAM is much more important in most contexts.